# Warning: Division by zero . First time when I see this error

Tags: php, divide-by-zero

Hello I have in unknow error like this :

```
Warning: Division by zero in /home/inv/public_html/items.php on line 71
Warning: Division by zero in /home/inv/public_html/items.php on line 84
```

Please help me because is first time when I see this error and ***I'm a beginner in .php*** . I really apreciate.

line 71 to 84

```html
      <span class="selector-chance">'.round(100*$sumvalue/$bank,1).'</span> %
      <span class="tooltip-content2 clearfix">
       <span class="tooltip-text2">
        Шанс выигрыша с этими предметами
        <a href="about.php">Читать подробнее</a>
       </span>
      </span>
     </h4>
    </div>
  </article>
  </section>';
  $td .= '<div class="players-percent-block" style="margin: 10px 6px;">
    <img src="'.$avatar.'">
    <div class="players-percent-text" style="font: 700 19px "RobotoRegular";">'.round(100*$sumvalue/$bank,1).'%</div>
```

Thank you guys !

Comment: I guess that your `$sumvalue` or `$bank` have zero value

Answer (score 1):

It seems value of your ***$bank*** variable is zero.